# Using Oauth to protect WebAPI with Azure active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I have browsed all the tutorials regarding using Oauth to protect WebAPI in Azure active directory online. But unfortunately, none of them can work.

I am using VS 2017 and my project is .net core.

So far what I have tried is:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMvc();
     ervices.AddAuthentication(); // -----------> newly added
 }
```

In "Configure", I added:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
     AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
     AutomaticChallenge = true,
     Authority = String.Format(Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"], Configuration["AzureAD:Tenant"]),
     Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:Audience"],         
 });
```

Here is my config:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "AadInstance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}",
    "Tenant": "tenantname.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Audience": "https://tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/webapiservice"
  }
```

I have registered this "webapiservice" (link is: http://webapiservice.azurewebsites.net) on my AAD.

Also, to access this web api service, I created a webapi client "webapiclient" which is also a web api and also registered it on my AAD and requested permission to access "webapiservice". The webapi client link is:  http://webapiclient.azurewebsites.net

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://webapiservice.azurewebsites.net/");
//is this uri correct? should it be the link of webapi service or the one of webapi client?

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/values").Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
     var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<string>>().Result;
     return result;
}
else
{
     return new string[] { "Something wrong" };
}
```

So theoretically, I should receive the correct results from webapiservice. but I always received "Something wrong".

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: You are not adding the authentication token to the request?

Comment: what does that mean？ Isn't it managed by AAD?

Comment: Your app must fetch it. It can use various ways to do that, for example it can use client id and secret to prove to AAD it is this app, and wants a token for that API. AAD will then give a token to you that you can attach to requests.

Comment: @juunas That is the part I am missing. How to retrieve the access token from AAD? Do you have an example to show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an **access token** from Azure AD.

There are plenty of good example apps on GitHub, here is one for a Daemon App: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon/blob/master/TodoListDaemon/Program.cs#L96

```
AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientCredential);
```

This app fetches an access token with its client id and client secret for an API. You can follow a similar approach in your case. You can just replace `todoListResourceId` with `"https://graph.windows.net/"` for Azure AD Graph API, or `"https://graph.microsoft.com/"` for Microsoft Graph API, for example. That is the identifier for the API that you want a token for.

This is the way it works in AAD. You want access to an API, you ask for that access from AAD. In a successful response you will get back an access token, that you must attach to the HTTP call as a header:

```
Authorization: Bearer accesstokengoeshere......
```

Now if you are building a web application, you may instead want to do it a bit differently, as you are now accessing the API as the client app, not the user. If you want to make a delegated call, then you will need to use e.g. the Authorization Code flow, where you show the user a browser, redirect them to the right address, and they get sent back to your app for login.

Answer (score 0):

To call web api protected by azure ad , you should pass this obtained access token in the authorization header  using a bearer scheme :

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
```

Comment: Would you like to elaborate a little bit more? How to get "authResult" in your example?

Comment: You could use openid connect/oauth2.0 authentication protocols with azure ad to get access token for resource whch protected by AAD, please check the [Authentication Scenarios for Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios) and [these code samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples) .